# how to show specific post details by clicking using react-router-parameters?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I'm using map to view all posts using axios. And I just want show when I click a specific post to see more information. I'm using react parameters. But it's not working.

Here is my one component

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'; 
import Album from './album'
import {Link, BrowserRouter as Router, Route} from 'react-router-dom'

import axios from "axios" 

class ViewDataAPI extends Component{

    state = {
        posts: []
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments')
        .then(response => {
            this.setState({
                posts: response.data
            })
        })
        .catch(error => console.log('error'))
    }

    render(){  
        let { posts } = this.state
        if(posts.length === 0){
            return <h1>Loading...</h1>
        }
        else{
            return(
                <Router>
                    <div className="header">
                        <div className="container">
                        <div className="row">
                                <div className="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                    <div className="text-center mb-20">
                                        <h1>View Data From API</h1>
                                        <p>using jsx-component, props, state, map in react </p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div> 
                            <div className="row">  
                                    {
                                        posts.map(post => 
                                            {
                                                return ( 
                                                        <Album 
                                                            key={post.id}  
                                                            name={post.name} 
                                                            email = {post.email} 
                                                            body = {post.body} 
                                                            view = {post.id} 

                                                        /> 
                                                )
                                            }
                                        )
                                    }   
                            </div>

                            {/* here is im using params, and to match by clicking specific id to show/view more information */}
                            <div className="row">  
                                  {posts && (
                                       <Route path="/album/:albumId" 
                                            render = {({match}) => (
                                                <ViewPosts {...posts.find(pv => pv.id === match.params.albumId)} />
                                            )}
                                       />
                                  )} 

                            </div>
                        </div> 
                    </div>
                </Router>
            )
        }


    }
}

export default ViewDataAPI;


// This component using for show details
const ViewPosts = ({posts}) =>{  
        return( 
            <div className="col-lg-6"> 
                <div className="card border-dark mb-3"> 
                    <div className="card-body text-dark">  
                        <div className="album">
                            <h3>{posts.name}</h3> 
                            <h3>{posts.email}</h3> 
                            <Link to="./">Back To Home</Link>

                        </div>
                    </div> 
                </div> 
            </div>   
        );

}
```

This is album component that has a link

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {Link} from "react-router-dom"

class Album extends Component{ 
    render(){ 
        return( 
            <div className="col-lg-6"> 
                <div className="card border-dark mb-3"> 
                    <div className="card-body text-dark">  
                        <div className="album">
                            <h3>{this.props.name}</h3>
                            <p>{this.props.email}</p>  
                            <p>{this.props.body}</p> 
                            <Link to={`/album/${this.props.view}`}>View</Link> 
                        </div>
                    </div> 
                </div> 
            </div>   
        );
    }
}

export default Album;
```

https://react-pin.netlify.com/

Please follow the above link to what I'm trying to do. Please first go to  one `"View Data From API"`

My github link https://github.com/sultan0/reactpin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The route param is a string. There is no implicit type conversion
  with `===` Operator. Therefore you have to do it explicitly. Pls. see
  [Comparison operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators) for a further explanation.
- The spread `...` Operator is misplaced here.

The solution is:

```
 <ViewPosts posts={posts.find(pv => pv.id === parseInt(match.params.albumId))} />
```

**Update**

You would like to use the Switch component from react router:

> Switch is unique in that it renders a route exclusively. In contrast, every Route that matches the location renders inclusively.

Pls refer to [react router documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch).

I created a [pull request](https://github.com/sultan0/reactpin/pull/1) as an example. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, its work. but how can i show another pages or component. I create a component there I put this. ```<ViewPosts posts={posts.find(pv => pv.id === parseInt(match.params.albumId))} />```  but how can I pass the posts data from previous component to new component .

Comment: You already passing the post matching the path param albumId to the ViewPost Component. What would you like to achieve?

Comment: I want to show the ViewPost component details to new page. now its showing under bottom of existing page when I clicked. but I want, its showing another new page where just show post details.

Comment: Great. there lots of work to do. thanks for your help. :)